# NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MatDialogData! - when mocking dialog component in jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, mat-dialog

I have generated test case for dialog component using simontest extension in visual studio code. But i get the following error leading to the failure of spec.

**Dialog Component**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { UserEnrollUpdateDialogComponent } from './mgmt-user-management.component';

fdescribe('UserEnrollUpdateDialogComponent', () => {
  let component: UserEnrollUpdateDialogComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserEnrollUpdateDialogComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const matDialogStub = () => ({});      
    });
    const formBuilderStub = () => ({ group: object => ({}) });
    const routerStub = () => ({});
    const datePipeStub = () => ({ transform: (value, string) => ({}) });
   
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [
        UserEnrollUpdateDialogComponent,
        ConfirmDeleteModalComponent,
        MgmtUserManagementComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: MatDialog, useFactory: matDialogStub },       
        { provide: FormBuilder, useFactory: formBuilderStub },
        { provide: Router, useFactory: routerStub },
        { provide: DatePipe, useFactory: datePipeStub }        
      ]
    });
   
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserEnrollUpdateDialogComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create UserEnrollUpdateDialogComponent', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

**Error Logs**

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[InjectionToken MatDialogData -> InjectionToken MatDialogData]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

---

```
providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} }
  ]
```

Comment: Can you please provide solution to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75361422/typeerror-this-formbuilder-group-is-not-a-function-while-writing-jasmine-spec/75362525#75362525