# TypeError: this.formBuilder.group is not a function - while writing jasmine specs

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

TypeError: this.formBuilder.group is not a function

i have imported both FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule and providers is as follows:

```
providers: [
        
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useFactory: matDialogRefStub },
        { provide: FormBuilder, useFactory: formBuilderStub },
        { provide: DatePipe, useFactory: datePipeStub },
        { provide: MatDialog, useFactory: matDialogStub },
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} }
      ]
```

**Component Class method**

```
 buildCustomerTypeForm() {
    this.customerTypeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      tc_customer_type: ['', Validators.required],
      tc_pma_option: ['', Validators.required],
      tc_zip_codess: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

**Spec Code:**

```
    const formBuilderStub: FormBuilder = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(
      FormBuilder
    );
    component.customerTypeForm = formBuilderStub.group({
      tc_customer_type: ['', Validators.required],
      tc_pma_option: ['', Validators.required],
      tc_zip_codess: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    spyOn(formBuilderStub, 'group').and.callThrough();
    component.buildCustomerTypeForm();
    expect(formBuilderStub.group).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this line: `{ provide: FormBuilder, useFactory: formBuilderStub },` if you have imported `ReactiveFormsModule`. `ReactiveFormsModule` should be able to give you the actual `formBuilder`, no need to mock it.

Comment: Tried your approach but didn't work